# How to include a single resource from a filtered folder in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse has exclusion filters that can be used to remove things from the workspace that the user doesn't need (a build folder for example). It also has include filters that can be used to add only things that match the filter. Exclude filters trump include filters, to [quote the documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm):

> If both "Exclude" and "Include" resource filters exist in a given folder or project, only files and/or folders that match any of the "Include" filters **and** do not match any of the "Exclude" filters will be included in the workspace

This seems to preclude adding a single (or small group) of entries from within an excluded folder. Is there an elegant way to include `build/foo/bar/baz/generated.h` but exclude everything else in the `build` folder (which may consists of hundreds or thousands of files and folders)?

I'm aware that rather than just excluding `build` I could add multiple exclusion filters carefully crafted to catch everything except the files I care about but as this would be both time consuming and fragile I wondered if there was a better way.